# Missing Require Parameters for [Route: blalba.Destroy]

Tags: laravel, routes

### Error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: brands.destroy] [URI: brands/{brand}].

### I found this error for the first time and I have no idea about it.

#### Code

- View

```php
@foreach ($brands as $key => $brand)
<tr>
    <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
    <td>{{ $brand->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $brand->detail }}</td>
    <td>
        <form action="{{ route('brands.destroy',$brand->id) }}" method="POST">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('brands.show',$brand->id) }}">Show</a>
            @can('product-edit')
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('brands.edit',$brand->id) }}">Edit</a>
            @endcan
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            @can('product-delete')
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            @endcan
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

- Controller

```php
    public function destroy(Brand $brand)
        {
            $brand->delete();
            return redirect()->route('brands.index')
                ->with('success', 'Brand deleted successfully');
        }
```

- Route List

```php
+--------+-----------+---------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                             | Name                 | Action                                                                 | Middleware        |
+--------+-----------+---------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | brands                          | brands.index         | App\Http\Controllers\BrandController@index                             | web,auth          |
|        | POST      | brands                          | brands.store         | App\Http\Controllers\BrandController@store                             | web,auth          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | brands/create                   | brands.create        | App\Http\Controllers\BrandController@create                            | web,auth          |
|        | DELETE    | brands/{brand}                  | brands.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\BrandController@destroy                           | web,auth          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | brands/{brand}                  | brands.update        | App\Http\Controllers\BrandController@update                            | web,auth          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | brands/{brand}                  | brands.show          | App\Http\Controllers\BrandController@show                              | web,auth          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | brands/{brand}/edit             | brands.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\BrandController@edit                              | web,auth          |
+--------+-----------+---------------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: It would be great if we could see the controller method that returns that view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you contain many routes in one form?

```
<form action="{{ route('brands.destroy',$brand->id) }}" method="POST">
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('brands.show',$brand->id) }}">Show</a>
            @can('product-edit')
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('brands.edit',$brand->id) }}">Edit</a>
            @endcan
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            @can('product-delete')
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            @endcan
        </form>
```

Comment: Correct it by: ```<form action="{{route('brands.destroy',[$brand->id])}}" method="POST">
 @method('DELETE')
 @csrf
 <button type="submit">Delete</button>               
</form>```

Comment: May I should to move many routes in form like this?
`<form action="{{route('brands.destroy',[$brand->id])}}" method="POST">
                                @method('DELETE') @csrf <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                            </form>`

Comment: No, we shouldn't keep route in same form. isn't it?

Comment: Now I can see page without error, but when I want to try edit or delete, it can't.
And showing error message = 

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

Comment: Is it occurred after you deleted record?

Answer (score 0):

This can be because you need to define the param like so.
`<form action="{{ route('brands.destroy', ['brand' => $brand->id]) }}" method="POST">`

You don't always have to do this but i've ran into issues where I have had to.

If that is not the case I'm at a loss as it all looks good to me.

Comment: After change the form, it comes another error. 
```The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `$brand->id` is `null` or not.

It would be wise to pass the parameters to the `route` helper as an associative array if possible, an array at the least but for one parameter it will take a single value. If you pass a `null` value it is as though you are not passing a parameter at all though.

Comment: No, the `$brand->id` is not `null`

Comment: the UrlGenerator seems to disagree, assuming this code is actually what is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed

Change some code in view, from:

```
<form action="{{ route('brands.destroy', $brand->id) }}" method="POST">
    ...
    ...
</form>
```

To:

```
<form action="{{ route('brands.destroy', [$brand->id_brand]) }}" method="POST">
    ...
    ...
</form>
```